# SQL Server Difference (opposite of intersect)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking for the easist/most scalable way to do a set "difference" in SQL Server see below.
[image]

If you can't tell from the picture i am looking for everything that is not in the intersection.

I have seen one way to do it:

```
select * from (      
    (select 'test1' as a, 1 as b)
 union all
  (select 'test2' as a , 2 as b union all select 'test1' as a , 1 as b )
)un group by a,b  having count(1)=1
```

But i fear what would happen if i used two large sets (i will not be querying from select '' constant statements, my queries will be pulling from real tables.)

*EDIT:*

Possible solution...

```
drop table #temp_a;
drop table #temp_b;

 go


  select * into #temp_a from (
   select 1 as num, 'String' as two, 'int'as three, 'purple' as four union all
   select 2 as num, 'dog' as two, 'int'as three, 'purple' as four union all
   select 3 as num, 'dog' as two, 'int'as three, 'cat' as four ) a 

select * into #temp_b from (
  select 1 as num, 'String' as two, 'decimal'as three, 'purple' as four union all
  select 2 as num, 'dog' as two, 'int'as three, 'purple' as four union all
  select 3 as num, 'dog' as two, 'int'as three, 'dog' as four ) b 





   SELECT IsNull(a.num, b.num) A,IsNull(a.two, b.two) B, IsNull(a.three, b.three) C,                  
      IsNull(a.four, b.four) D 
     FROM #temp_a a 
   FULL OUTER JOIN #temp_b b ON (a.num=b.num AND a.two=b.two and a.three=b.three and a.four=b.four)
    WHERE   (a.num is null or b.num is null  )
```

RESULTS:

> 1 String  int purple
>
> 3 dog int cat
>
> 1 String  dec purple
>
> 3 dog int dog

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT A, B FROM Table1 EXCEPT SELECT A,B FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT A, B FROM Table2 EXCEPT SELECT A,B FROM Table1
```

Here is an example with the FULL OUTER JOIN method (assuming A is not nullable in both tables)

```
SELECT IsNull(Table1.A, Table2.A) a,IsNull(Table1.B, Table2.B) B
FROM Table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.A=Table2.A AND Table1.B=Table2.B)
WHERE Table1.A is null or Table2.A is null
```

Comment: What does the IsNull part achieve?  It it just a means to "show" what is missing?

Comment: For rows that only have a record in one of the tables (the ones you want) there will be a null in one table or the other. For example either Table1.A will be null or Table2.A will be null for each row. The Isnull grabs the value from whichever side has a value.

Comment: Question is about SQL Server, but comes up for general SQL searches. Note: IsNull(a,b) is Sql Server specific. The generic SQL equivalent is COALESCE(), and by the way, coalesce is actually more robust than IsNull since IsNull performs a replacement operation on a single argument.  Coalesce() takes any number of parameters and grabs the first non-null parameter.  Highly recommend coalesce always instead of IsNull

Comment: Also, IsNull is poorly named and not human-intuitive, since it sounds like it only does a simple True/False test with return instead of an optional replacement operation.

Answer (score 16):

Alternative:

```
SELECT A, B FROM Table1 UNION SELECT A,B FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT A, B FROM Table2 INTERSECT SELECT A,B FROM Table1
```

Comment: +1

I see a user-defined function coming out of this...

    `with A as (
      select A, B
      from A
    ),
    B as (
      select A, B
      from B
    )
    select * from A union select * from B
    except
    select * from A intersect select * from B;`

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is called a [Full Outer Join, which SQL Server supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx).

Comment: I initially thought something like that:
select * from 
  (select 'test1' as a, 1 as b) One
FULL JOIN
  (select 'test2' as a , 2 as b union all select 'test1' as a , 1 as b ) Two
 ON One.a <> Two.a AND One.b <> Two.b

However it's not (run both SQL)

Comment: yes, but you also have to filter out all the matches after the join: `WHERE keyA is NULL OR keyB is NULL`

Comment: A full outer join is NOT what the question is asking for. A full outer join would be the Venn Diagram completely filled in, not just the non-intersecting portions of the Venn Diagram.