# MS Access SQL error in From Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do a set difference as shown by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260392/sql-server-difference-opposite-of-intersect) question, except I am doing it in Microsoft Access. The SQL query I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT FieldName
FROM CalParams_External
EXCEPT SELECT FieldName
FROM CalParams_Internal
UNION
SELECT FieldName
FROM CalParams_Internal
EXCEPT SELECT FieldName
FROM CalParams_External
```

When I run this however it throws an error:

> Syntax error in FROM clause

I'd like to get this to work. What am I doing wrong here and how can I get this simple script to run?

**EDIT**

According to the comment below, JET does not support the `EXCEPT` statement. I would like to break down the problem by finding the non-intersecting part of only one of the datasets using the `MINUS` statement instead (which I believe is supported). Here's what I'm doing now:

```
SELECT FieldName
From CalParams_External
MINUS
SELECT FieldName
FROM CalParams_Internal
```

I'm still getting the same error regarding the `FROM` clause though.

Comment: JET doesn't support EXCEPT.

Comment: so how can I do this on JET?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MS Access doesn't support `EXCEPT`, use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` instead. `NOT IN` is more readable, but only works on non-null columns.

**NOT IN query:**

```
SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_External
WHERE FieldName NOT IN (SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_Internal)
UNION
SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_Internal
WHERE FieldName NOT IN (SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_External);
```

**NOT EXISTS query:**

```
SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_External e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CalParams_Internal i WHERE i.FieldName = e.FieldName)
UNION
SELECT FieldName FROM CalParams_Internal i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CalParams_External e WHERE e.FieldName = i.FieldName)
```

**Aggregation query:**

An alternative would be to select each FiedName once from each table and then pick those that only occur in one of them:

```
SELECT FieldName
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM CalParams_External
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM CalParams_Internal
)
GROUP BY FieldName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: It appears to work but I would like to see if the `MINUS` statement can be used in this context. Could you add one option for a `MINUS` query?

Comment: MS Access doen't support `EXCEPT` which is standard SQL nor `MINUS` which is Oracle proprietary. I've added an alternative to my answer, but you have nothing like `EXCEPT` in MS Access.